# Spacial pyramid pooling in tensorflow with unknown shape

Tags: tensorflow, spatial-pooling

I would like to perform spacial pyramid pooling in tensorflow. This has already been answered [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6011) (and other questions in Stackoverflow.com), but the proposed solution doesn't work with unknown input shape.

Is there an implementation that handles unknown shapes at graph definition?

Comment: Share the code which you are using for SPP. Consider adding more details regarding your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The code I use is similar to the code given in the link. However, I made another implementation that solves the problem. I'm gonna write it as an answer to the question. If my question is unclear, please share how I could improve it for better visibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address this issue, I came up with a different implementation that uses a mask, rescaled using nearest neighbor:

```
def avg_spp(self, input, scale, name, padding=DEFAULT_PADDING):
    eye = tf.eye(scale*scale, batch_shape=(tf.shape(input)[0],))
    mask = tf.reshape(eye, (-1, scale, scale, scale*scale))
    mask = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(mask, tf.shape(input)[1:3])
    spp = tf.multiply(tf.expand_dims(input, 4), tf.expand_dims(mask, 3))
    spp = tf.divide(tf.reduce_sum(spp, axis=[1,2]), tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(spp, axis=[1,2]), tf.float32))
    spp = tf.reshape(spp, (-1, tf.shape(input)[3], scale, scale))
    spp = tf.transpose(spp, [0,2,3,1], name=name)
    return spp
```